# SOAP fault message <faultcode>S:Server</faultcode> cannot be cast to

Tags: web-services, soap, jde

en I am inserting three input in SOAP request and when trying to get a response I am getting fault message specifying that cannot be cast to a class.

Here I have attached the SOAP response which I am facing.

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
<S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <faultcode>S:Server</faultcode>
  <faultstring>...bssv.J570040.valueobject.InternalOrderVO cannot be cast to ...bssv.JP570040.valueobject.IntermediateShipDet</faultstring>
  <detail>
    <ns2:exception xmlns:ns2="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/" class="java.lang.ClassCastException" note="To disable this feature, set com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.disableCaptureStackTrace system property to false">
      <message>bssv.J570040.valueobject.InternalOrderVO cannot be cast to bssv.JP570040.valueobject.IntermediateShipDet</message>
      <ns2:stackTrace>
        <ns2:frame class="bssv.JP570040.valueobject.showOrderDetVO" file="showOrderDetVO.java" line="123" method="<init>" />
        <ns2:frame class="bssv.JP570040.InvokeShippingDet" file="InvokeShippingDet.java" line="82" method="GetShippingOrder" />
        <ns2:frame class="bssv.JP570040.InvokeShippingDet" file="InvokeShippingDet.java" line="39" method="GetShippingOrder" />
        <ns2:frame class="sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl" file="NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java" line="native" method="invoke0" />
        <ns2:frame class="sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl" file="NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java" line="39" method="invoke" />
        <ns2:frame class="sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl" file="DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java" line="25" method="invoke" />
        <ns2:frame class="java.lang.reflect.Method" file="Method.java" line="597" method="invoke" />
        <ns2:frame class="weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker" file="WLSInstanceResolver.java" line="92" method="invoke" />
        <ns2:frame class="weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker" file="WLSInstanceResolver.java" line="74" method="invoke" />
        <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2" file="InvokerTube.java" line="151" method="invoke" />
        <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandlerImpl" file="EndpointMethodHandlerImpl.java" line="268" method="invoke" />
        <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube" file="SEIInvokerTube.java" line="100" method="processRequest" />
        <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="866" method="__doRun" />
        <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="815" method="_doRun" />
        <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="778" method="doRun" />
        <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="680" method="runSync" />
        <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2" file="WSEndpointImpl.java" line="403" method="process" />
        <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit" file="HttpAdapter.java" line="532" method="handle" />
        <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter" file="HttpAdapter.java" line="253" method="handle" />
        <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter" file="ServletAdapter.java" line="140" method="handle" />
        <ns2:frame class="weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSServletAdapter" file="WLSServletAdapter.java" line="171" method="handle" />
        <ns2:frame class="weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$AuthorizedInvoke" file="HttpServletAdapter.java" line="708" method="run" />
        <ns2:frame class="weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject" file="AuthenticatedSubject.java" line="363" method="doAs" />
        <ns2:frame class="weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager" file="SecurityManager.java" line="146" method="runAs" />
        <ns2:frame class="weblogic.wsee.util.ServerSecurityHelper" file="ServerSecurityHelper.java" line="103" method="authenticatedInvoke" />
        <ns2:frame class="weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$3" file="HttpServletAdapter.java" line="311" method="run" />
        <ns2:frame class="weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter" file="HttpServletAdapter.java" line="336" method="post" />
        <ns2:frame class="weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet" file="JAXWSServlet.java" line="95" method="doRequest" />
        <ns2:frame class="weblogic.servlet.http.AbstractAsyncServlet" file="AbstractAsyncServlet.java" line="99" method="service" />
        <ns2:frame class="javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" file="HttpServlet.java" line="820" method="service" />
        <ns2:frame class="weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction" file="StubSecurityHelper.java" line="227" method="run" />
        <ns2:frame class="weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper" file="StubSecurityHelper.java" line="125" method="invokeServlet" />
        <ns2:frame class="weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl" file="ServletStubImpl.java" line="300" method="execute" />
        <ns2:frame class="weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter" file="TailFilter.java" line="26" method="doFilter" />
        <ns2:frame class="weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl" file="FilterChainImpl.java" line="56" method="doFilter" />
        <ns2:frame class="oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1" file="JpsAbsFilter.java" line="111" method="run" />
        <ns2:frame class="java.security.AccessController" file="AccessController.java" line="native" method="doPrivileged" />
        <ns2:frame class="oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject" file="JpsSubject.java" line="313" method="doAsPrivileged" />
        <ns2:frame class="oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil" file="JpsPlatformUtil.java" line="413" method="runJaasMode" />
        <ns2:frame class="oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter" file="JpsAbsFilter.java" line="94" method="runJaasMode" />
        <ns2:frame class="oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter" file="JpsAbsFilter.java" line="161" method="doFilter" />
        <ns2:frame class="oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter" file="JpsFilter.java" line="71" method="doFilter" />
        <ns2:frame class="weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl" file="FilterChainImpl.java" line="56" method="doFilter" />
        <ns2:frame class="oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter" file="DMSServletFilter.java" line="136" method="doFilter" />
        <ns2:frame class="weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl" file="FilterChainImpl.java" line="56" method="doFilter" />
        <ns2:frame class="weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction" file="WebAppServletContext.java" line="3715" method="wrapRun" />
        <ns2:frame class="weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction" file="WebAppServletContext.java" line="3681" method="run" />
        <ns2:frame class="weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject" file="AuthenticatedSubject.java" line="321" method="doAs" />
        <ns2:frame class="weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager" file="SecurityManager.java" line="120" method="runAs" />
        <ns2:frame class="weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext" file="WebAppServletContext.java" line="2277" method="securedExecute" />
        <ns2:frame class="weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext" file="WebAppServletContext.java" line="2183" method="execute" />
        <ns2:frame class="weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl" file="ServletRequestImpl.java" line="1454" method="run" />
        <ns2:frame class="weblogic.work.ExecuteThread" file="ExecuteThread.java" line="209" method="execute" />
        <ns2:frame class="weblogic.work.ExecuteThread" file="ExecuteThread.java" line="178" method="run" />
      </ns2:stackTrace>
    </ns2:exception>
  </detail>
</S:Fault>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the error I would assume that, there is an error converting internal data item from Date type to external data item of Calendar data type.
Please find a sample of such conversion in bssv

```
 public Calendar setCalendar(Date date)
  {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    if (date != null)
    {
      cal.setTime(date);
    }
    return cal;
  }
```